# Ошибка при импорте БД в phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Понадобилось написать сервер на php с mysql. Нашел сайт с бесплатным хостингом, создал там БД, открываю управление через phpmyadmin, которое там уже есть. Пытаюсь сначала с нуля создать БД, вылетают ошибки, которых на самом деле нет. Достало это, поэтому решил сделать скрипт через mysql workbench и импортировать его в phpmyadmin, но и тут не так всё просто...

Пожалуйста, подскажите что нужно сделать, чтобы избавиться от этой ошибки и наконец произвести импорт?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сам скрипт:

```
-- MySQL Script generated by MySQL Workbench
-- Mon May 14 13:42:58 2018
-- Model: New Model    Version: 1.0
-- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema galos_db
-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema galos_db
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `galos_db` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `galos_db` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `galos_db`.`users`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `galos_db`.`users` (
  `_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `login` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `money` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `record` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`_id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `idtable1_UNIQUE` (`_id` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `login_UNIQUE` (`login` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `email_UNIQUE` (`email` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `galos_db`.`achievements`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `galos_db`.`achievements` (
  `_id` INT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `status` VARCHAR(26) NOT NULL DEFAULT '00000000000000000000000000',
  `all_levels` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `all_money` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `all_eating` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `all_wins` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `id_user` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`_id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `_id_UNIQUE` (`_id` ASC),
  INDEX `id_user_idx` (`id_user` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `achievementsUserFK`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_user`)
    REFERENCES `galos_db`.`users` (`_id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `galos_db`.`resume`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `galos_db`.`resume` (
  `_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `mode` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `score` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `all_rewards` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `id_user` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`_id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `_id_UNIQUE` (`_id` ASC),
  INDEX `id_user_idx` (`id_user` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `resumeUserFK`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_user`)
    REFERENCES `galos_db`.`users` (`_id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Comment: Ну русским же по белому пишут - Access denied. Что в переводе с басурманского означает, что прав у тебя нету - базы создавать. на бесплатном хостинге - обычное дело. Там тебе одну БД создали, и в ней варись.

Answer (score -1):

Просто чудотворный сайт. Как только я теряю все силы и надежды, как только я решаюсь оставить здесь вопрос, так вдруг ко мне приходит "озарение" и я решаю свою проблему сам...

В скрипте у меня речь идёт о бд `galos_db`, а в phpmyadmin она называлась, пусть `example_db`. Заменил в скрипте `galos_db` на `example_db` и всё заработало без единой ошибки.

Comment: Ну так удалите вопрос...

Comment: Как его удалить?